# As the beneficiary of a trust, do the trust payments count as support for the beneficiary?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Let's say that a person is a full time student under 24 and the beneficiary of a trust. Do the trust payments count as self support for tax purposes?  Can you provide a source for your answer?

EDIT: The question is if this counts as support as described by the rules for whether one qualifies as a dependent.

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of corpus (principal) is not taxed, the K-1 would reflect pass through taxable items such as dividends or capital gains looking no different on the kid's 1040 than if he owned the stocks. 
I've handled trusts and the K-1 reporting for 10 years. This is how it is.